# IntelliJ plugin autocomplete formatting

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete, formatting, intellij-plugin

I add an autocomplete fonctionnality to my IntelliJ plugin like this :

```
String completionString = "myFunction(err, data){if(err){}else{}}";
return LookupElementBuilder
                .create(completionString)
                .withBoldness(true)
                .withIcon(SailsJSIcons.SailsJS)
                .withPresentableText("myFunction()")
                .withCaseSensitivity(true)
                .withTypeText(type)
                .withTailText(" (" + item + ")", true)
                .withAutoCompletionPolicy(AutoCompletionPolicy.GIVE_CHANCE_TO_OVERWRITE);
```

How can I format the new method I will put on editor ? I don't want a custom formatting, just want the default formatting of IntelliJ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an InsertHandler to your LookupElement and perform `CodeStyleManager.reformat(psiElement)` in its `handleInsert` method.

However, I don't see why you're making this available through a completion contributor at all. This looks like a live template, and your plugin can contribute live templates with far less effort than custom completion. Live templates are automatically shown in completion lists and support automatic reformatting.

Comment: Do you have an example please ? also for live template ? If live templates are more easy to use and work with completion I take it ^^. I want to generate automatically a nodeJS basic function structure like Model.myfunc -> completion -> Model.myfunction(function(param1,...){...});

Comment: For CodeStyleManager.reformat under handleInsert the psiElement is null :(

Comment: Which psiElement is null? You need to locate the element you've inserted manually.

Comment: handleInsert(InsertionContext context, LookupElement item) I just test item.getPsiElement() but this one is null

Comment: Yes, of course. You need to use InsertionContext.getStartOffset() to locate the inserted element in the PSI file.

Comment: Ho thanks, I think I use the hard way ^^ did you have some example for doing this with live template like you said ?

Comment: An example of what exactly? To contribute live templates from a plugin, you need to implement DefaultLiveTemplatesProvider.

Comment: You said in your answer that I'm doing it in the wrong way and I should use live template. So I want to test it with template. Thanks I will try DefaultLiveTemplatesProvider

Comment: Much easier with templates ^^ thanks but it's possible to add a custom icon to live template ? For user know it's for the current framework ? For now there no icon at all

Comment: Just make some test and live templates are not under autocompletion at first, they only appear when the full texte was written or if we make a second ctr+space. Example I set an "update" template, when I write Post. update was not on choice, if i write Post.up it's not show but if I make another ctr+space then update for on autocomplete. Is there a way to force the visibility ?